# .NET equivalent of "net group /domain"?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

If I run 'net group /domain' on the Windows command line, I get a list of "global groups" for the current domain server. I want to get the same list from my .NET code.

Googling around I find thousands of "How to get the groups a user belongs to", "How to get the users that belong to a group", etc. I just want the list of *all* global groups; not those associated with a particular user. Can someone show me the code for this, or reference from which that code could be derived?

Comment: See the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will find all Global groups in the current domain:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (var filter = new GroupPrincipal(context) { GroupScope = GroupScope.Global })
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(filter))
{
    var groups = searcher.FindAll();
}
```

Comment: Where does the `.Dump()` come from?  I don't see it defined anywhere.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx

Comment: @BACON - Sorry.  `Dump()` was left over from my testing in LinqPad.  I've taken it out of the answer.

Comment: What resource did you learn the API from (aka, teach a man fish)?